# How do I update a table in MySQL in the 1and1 domain?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a master table called client names.  The key field is clientid and is a char 36.  I have an address table.  I need to update the address table's clientid fied, define the same as above, with the value from clientnames.  My SQL runs but no rows are update.  My first SQL is:

```
UPDATE address
SET clientid = 
(
    SELECT c.clientid FROM clientnames c 
    JOINrempAddress ra ON c.lastname = ra.lastname AND c.firstname = ra.firstname
)
```

The inner select returns the values I expect.

I have even tried:

```
UPDATE address SET clientid = 'AB3'.
```

Still no rows are updated.  What am I doing wrong?  Is 1and1 MySQL different and thus has different syntax?

Thank you.

Comment: I am sure 1and1 is no different. What you aren't showing us is the script. In there lies your problem.

Comment: Both of your queries are correct. Where are you executing them?

Comment: I have found my problem.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that there were trailing spaces in the first name on one of the tables.  When I used the TRIM function it worked as expected.